# reading the content of BPMN file

Tags: javascript, bpmn

```
window.onload = function () {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');


    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var a = reader.result;
                //alert(a);
                importXML(a);
            }

            reader.readAsText(file);
        } else {
            alert('file not supported');
        }
    });
}
```

I am using the above javascript code to read the content of file and its working fine for the file having extension .txt . I want my code to read the content of file having extension .bpmn . Can anybody please give me some suggestions to implement this functionality

Comment: If you select a file with extension .bpmn, what value do you get for *file.type*? Also, more semantic to use `textType.test(file.type)` which returns true or false rather than *match* which returns *null* or an array.

Comment: ok RobG thanks for your suggestion . Let me try this and will let u know whether its working or not

Comment: RobG still its not working , I changed the condition as per your suggestion , but the provlem remains the same

Comment: File type should be BPMN

Comment: Please define "_not working_".